# sharing calendar information exchange online

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange

We have several tenants setup in office 365 from various acquisitions.  We wanted users to be able to see each others' calendars across tenants.  We followed the docs on [inter-tenant collaboration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-inter-tenant-collaboration?view=o365-worldwide) and [organization relationships](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/sharing/organization-relationships/organization-relationships?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and we then proceeded to add an organization relationship in powershell:

```
New-OrganizationRelationship -Name "domain_1" \
  -Domains "domain_1.com" \
  -FreeBusyAccessEnabled:$true \
  -FreeBusyAccessLevel limitedDetails
```

After doing that, we still were not able to see availability across the tenants in exchange.  Are there any subsequent steps after creating the organization relationship that we missed?

Output of `Get-MailboxFolderPermission`:

```
RunspaceId             : f970****-****-****-****-************
Identity               : ******:\Calendar
FolderName             : Calendar
User                   : Default
AccessRights           : {AvailabilityOnly}
SharingPermissionFlags :
IsValid                : True
ObjectState            : New
```

Output of `Get-SharingPolicy`:

```
RunspaceId        : f970****-****-****-****-************
Domains           : {Anonymous:CalendarSharingFreeBusyReviewer, *:CalendarSharingFreeBusySimple}
Enabled           : True
Default           : True
AdminDisplayName  :
ExchangeVersion   : 0.10 (14.0.100.0)
Name              : Default Sharing Policy
DistinguishedName : CN=Default Sharing Policy,CN=Federation,CN=Configuration,***
Identity          : Default Sharing Policy
ObjectCategory    : *********01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Sharing-Policy
ObjectClass       : {top, msExchSharingPolicy}
WhenChanged       : 2019-10-13 05:45:19 am
WhenCreated       : 2016-07-06 11:57:04 am
WhenChangedUTC    : 2019-10-13 10:45:19 am
WhenCreatedUTC    : 2016-07-06 04:57:04 pm
ExchangeObjectId  : 65db****-****-****-****-************
OrganizationId    : *********01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations/***
Id                : Default Sharing Policy
Guid              : 65db****-****-****-****-************
OriginatingServer : SN***********01.NAMPR15A001.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
IsValid           : True
ObjectState       : Changed
```

Comment: Did you run `Get-OrganizationRelationship | fl` to check whether the relationship was created? Are you running EXO hybrid? If so, did you correctly setup the autodiscover URL? For hybrid, it must point to an on-premises exchange server. Did you check permissions if the calendars actually grant you the permission to view  free/busy information?

Comment: Yes, we ran the Get-organizationRelationship, and the relationship was created.  We are not running hybrid.  How would we check permissions?  Check each  every individual user?  e.g., in outlook intra-tenant, I can already see coworker's availability, but I can't see the availability of coworkers in the sister tenant.  Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Pick one user (and stick with that for further troubleshooting) and check the *Default* calendar permissions via PowerShell (`Get-MailboxFolderPermission "<userPrincipalName>\Calendar"`). Also check your sharing Policy (`Get-SharingPolicy`). Check the description for [Set-SharingPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-sharingpolicy?view=exchange-ps) for details.

Comment: Updated above.  I didn't see anything that would prevent viewing availability, but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Does not look wrong. If you don't find the solution, you can always open a support ticket with Microsoft, if you have the mental strength for it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, you should configure Office 365 share free busy between tenant, in other words, you should configure organization relationships in all these several tenants. Steps for your reference: [Configuring Office 365 share free busy between tenant](https://msexperttalk.com/office-365-share-free-busy-tenants/)

In addition, Cross-tenant configurations do not support personal contacts for free/busy lookup. Contacts must be included in the global address list for free/busy lookup to work. Above is mentioned in the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/sharing/organization-relationships/create-an-organization-relationship#use-the-exchange-admin-center-to-create-an-organization-relationship).

Comment: Thanks, we read the same articles, and we did configure across all the tenants but that ended up not showing us availability either.

Comment: Have you tried to share calendar with your tenants users? Do the user see the shared calendar free/busy information? Or add shared calendar manually?